# How do i select distinct values from multiple columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql, join, combobox

I know this question has been asked, but I have not found a viable answer that addresses my specific problem.

I have a single table (in MySQL) with 4 columns (first name, last name, account number, and organization). In my program I want to create 4 drop down (combo boxes) (one for each column). The combo boxes contain the unique values of that column. Right now, I accomplish it by using 4 separate SQL queries and then populating each combo box. I was trying to see if there is a faster way by doing a single query to get all the values and then just separate them into the combo boxes after I get the results. But I cannot figure out how to do it with a single query, I have tried every join in the book and using derived tables and everything I can think of, but nothing has worked.

Basically my first name combo box, needs to contain all of the distinct first names in the table, the second combo box contains all the distinct last names, 3rd the distinct acct. numbers and 4th, the distinct organizations with no duplicates in any combo box.

Is this possible and if so how? Thanks.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
Select distinct firstname from t1 order by firstname;
' populate my combo box

Select  distinct lastname from t1 order by lastname;
; populate my combo box

etc...
```

Comment: I think you can just return the whole dataset in one query, and handle the display logic at the application level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here is basically the optimal strategy. This is just how SQL works.

Consider how the output would be if you were trying to list, simultaneously, all `firstname` and `lastname` entries simultaneously. How many rows would you get for 6 distinct first names and 8 distinct last names? 6? 8? 48?

If this is too slow, what you need to do is properly `INDEX` your columns so that the `DISTINCT` operation itself is faster.

Comment: Thanks, everything is indexed accordingly. I was just trying to see if I could gain some speed by doing it in one query as there are 468,000 entries in the table and I query it 4 times. Although indexed, it takes about 3 seconds to run all 4 queries.

Comment: Sounds like you need to cache the results.